# C++ Explicit Instantiation of a Function

Tags: c++, function, instantiation, explicit

I'm writing my own library for the fun of it and I've run into an issue.  Here is my code.

```
#include "utility/memory.h"
using namespace libnate::utility;

template <class T>
void copy( T *src, T *dest, size_t size ) {
        for( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
                dest[i] = src[i];
        }
}

template void copy( int *, int *, size_t );

template <class T>
size_t resize_array( T *&array, size_t internal_size ) {
        size_t nu_size = internal_size * 2 + 1;

        T *tmp_array = new T[nu_size];
        copy<T> ( array, tmp_array, internal_size );
        delete [] array;

        array = tmp_array;
        return nu_size;
}

template size_t resize_array( int *&, size_t );
```

G++ is complaining about some sort of ambiguous call in my call to copy.

Here is the output.

```
njackson@glados:~/libnate$ make
cd src && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/njackson/libnate/src'
g++ -c -I../include memory.cpp  
memory.cpp: In function ‘size_t resize_array(T*&, size_t) [with T = int, size_t = unsigned int]’:
memory.cpp:25:46:   instantiated from here
memory.cpp:18:2: error: call of overloaded ‘copy(int*&, int*&, size_t&)’ is ambiguous
memory.cpp:18:2: note: candidates are:
memory.cpp:5:6: note: void copy(T*, T*, size_t) [with T = int, size_t = unsigned int]
../include/utility/memory.h:11:6: note: void libnate::utility::copy(T*, T*, size_t) [with T = int, size_t = unsigned int]
make[1]: *** [memory.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/njackson/libnate/src'
make: *** [_] Error 2
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems pretty clear that the namespace `libnate::utility` includes a function named `copy`. Since you are defining your own, and have a `using namespace libnate::utility` statement at the beginning of your code, you get a name clash.

I recommend removing the `using namespace` statement. Keeping it may cause a whole lot of other symbols to be introduced into your code, possibly causing further name clashes in the future.

If you really want to keep the statement, either use `::copy` to refer to your own version of the copy function, or just rename it into `mycopy` or something like that.

---

On a separate note, your explicit instantiation of the `copy` function (which does not cause the problem anyway) is not actually necessary. `resize_array` uses your `copy` function and therefore will cause the required instantiations automatically.

Comment: Makes sense, however, I would like to be able to use the copy function outside of the resize_array function.

Comment: Whereever you use it, as long as the template definition is available, the compiler will instantiate it automatically. You need an explicit instantiation only if you want to be able to use the function when only its declaration, but not definition, is available (e.g. when the definition is in a .cpp file, and somewhere else you include the .h file and link to the object file generated from the .cpp). Anyway, the cause of the problem at hand is the name clash, not the explicit instantiation.